# Remove() function doesn't remove the element from BST

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to add a remove method to my BST But I just can't figure out what is wrong. I have defined the `pointer` variable using `let` but it's still not working. It seems like it doesn't update the `root` object.

```
const Node = (data, left = null, right = null) => {
    return {data, left, right};
};

const Tree = array => {

    const remDupsAndSort = array => {
        const mergeSort = array => {
            if(array.length <= 1) return array;
            let leftArr = array.slice(0, array.length / 2);
            let rightArr = array.slice(array.length / 2);
            return merge(mergeSort(rightArr), mergeSort(leftArr))
        
        };
        
        const merge = (leftArr, rightArr) => {
            let sorted = [];
            while(leftArr.length && rightArr.length){
                if(leftArr[0] < rightArr[0]){
                    sorted.push(leftArr.shift());
                }else{
                    sorted.push(rightArr.shift());
                }
            };
            return [...sorted, ...leftArr, ...rightArr]
        };
        return mergeSort([... new Set(array)])
    };

    array = remDupsAndSort(array);

    const buildTree = (array, start, end) => {
        if(start > end) return null;
        let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        let node = Node(array[mid]);
        node.left = buildTree(array, start, mid - 1);
        node.right = buildTree(array, mid + 1, end);
        return node;
    };
    
    

    const remove = value => {
        if(!root) return root;
        let pointer = root;
        while(pointer){
            if(value < pointer.data){
                pointer = pointer.left
            }
            else if(value > pointer.data){
                pointer = pointer.right;
            }else{
                if(!pointer.right && !pointer.left){
                    return null;
                }
                if(!pointer.left){
                    return pointer.right;
                }else if(!pointer.right){
                    return pointer.left;
                }else{
                    let nextBiggest = pointer.right;
                    while(nextBiggest.left){
                        nextBiggest = nextBiggest.left;
                    }
                    return pointer = nextBiggest;
                }    
            }
        }
    };
    
    
    let root = buildTree(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    return {root, remove}
};
```

When I run the code it doesn't remove anything from the tree. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`let pointer = root;` will assign the value of `root` to the `pointer` variable. Changing the value of `pointer` will not change the value of the original variable though. The variable is an object, and changing the key values within that object will cause the original to change.

So you either need to set the value of each key individually (which won't work really in this case because you want to set the whole value to be null sometimes), or you can track the parent value as you traverse through the tree so that you can modify `parent.left` and `parent.right` (or go a completely different route make a recursive removal function)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @abney317 the problem was solved by tracking the parent nodes. Although I'm not happiest with this code and it's not the most good looking code I've done, but I'm sharing it here just in case some one needed it.

```
const remove = value => {
        if(!root) return root;
        let pointer = root;
        let parent = null;
        while(pointer){
            if(value < pointer.data){
                parent = pointer;
                pointer = pointer.left
            }
            else if(value > pointer.data){
                parent = pointer;
                pointer = pointer.right;
            }else{
                if(!pointer.right && !pointer.left){
                    if(pointer === parent.left) return parent.left = null;
                    if(pointer === parent.right) return parent.right = null;
                }
                if(!pointer.left){
                    if(pointer === parent.left) return parent.left = pointer.right
                    if(pointer === parent.right) return parent.right = pointer.right
                }else if(!pointer.right){
                    if(pointer === parent.left) return parent.left = pointer.left
                    if(pointer === parent.right) return parent.right = pointer.left
                }else{
                    let replacingNode = pointer.right;
                    let replacingParent = pointer;
                    while(replacingNode.left){
                        replacingParent = replacingNode;
                        replacingNode = replacingNode.left;
                    }
                    if(pointer === root){
                        replacingNode.right = root.right;
                        replacingNode.left = root.left;
                        root = replacingNode;
                        if(replacingNode === replacingParent.left) return replacingParent.left = null;
                        if(replacingNode === replacingParent.right) return replacingParent.right = null;

                    }
                    if(pointer === parent.left){
                        if(replacingNode === pointer.left){
                            replacingNode.left = null;
                        }else{
                            replacingNode.left = pointer.left;
                        }
                        if(replacingNode === pointer.right){
                            replacingNode.right = null;
                        }else{
                            replacingNode.right = pointer.right;
                        }
                        parent.left = replacingNode;
                        if(replacingNode === replacingParent.left) return replacingParent.left = null;
                        if(replacingNode === replacingParent.right) return replacingParent.right = null;
                    } 
                    if(pointer === parent.right){
                        if(replacingNode === pointer.left){
                            replacingNode.left = null;
                        }else{
                            replacingNode.left = pointer.left;
                        }
                        if(replacingNode === pointer.right){
                            replacingNode.right = null;
                        }else{
                            replacingNode.right = pointer.right;
                        }
                        parent.right = replacingNode;  
                        if(replacingNode === replacingParent.left) return replacingParent.left = null;
                        if(replacingNode === replacingParent.right) return replacingParent.right = null;
                    } 
                }    
            }
        }
    };
```